# DataGrid.SortMemberPath doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, wpftoolkit

I created a `DataGrid` with binding to `DataTable`, here:

```
<DataGrid1:DataGrid x:Name="dg" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}">
<DataGrid1:DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="[First Column name]" Header="First Column name">
      <DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding [First Column name],Mode=TwoWay}" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid1:DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid1:DataGrid>
```

and when I click on header to sort the table, I get this exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'My_Table_Name' type does not have property named '[First Column name]', so cannot sort data collection.

Comment: you post your answer:  'My_Table_Name' type does not have property named '[First Column name]', so cannot sort data collection

Comment: OMG.  replace [First Column name] with First Column name....  -1 Vote for this one. Read error messages please.

Comment: if you use a typed datatable it would work. i dont know wether SortMemberPath can work with indexer...

Comment: i read this error messages more than one time.. but i dont know thet it's work without [] becouse the DataContext is DadaRow ,and also DataTable does not have property named 'First Column name'...  but its working good!

Answer (score 4):

`SortMemberPath` is meant to point to a string containing the property name, NOT to a binding.

You can use `[FirstColumnName]` in your `TextBox.Text` because it is a binding, so is binding to `DataRow[FirstColumnName]`

`SortMemberPath` is a property name, so is trying to reference `DataRow.[FirstColumnName]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Zeps You said in your question it was giving you an exception.... Using the square brackets in a binding should be fine, but using it in the `SortMemberPath` won't work because it's not a property name.